# Spring Boot: disable https for actuator endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, https, spring-boot-actuator

Is possible to config Spring Booot application to have some url with non-secure (non-https) ex: /actuator/info, /actuator/prometheous While All other enpoint forced to be secure?

Enable SSL like this:

```
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=xxxx
```

I was try to set:

```
management.server.port=8762
management.server.ssl.enabled=false
```

and

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.requiresChannel().antMatchers("/actuator").requiresInsecure();
    http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
    // accept only IP in range to access metric
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/actuator/**")
            .access("hasIpAddress('" + ipRangeMain + "') or hasIpAddress('" + ipRangeSecond + "')");

}
```

But it's still not working
When I try to access /actuator/info, it show error:

```
Bad Request
This combination of host and port requires TLS.
```

"/actuator/info" endpoint need to accessed by Load Balancer and "/actuator/prometheous" to Monitoring, But now it not work.

Comment: In this configuration `http.requiresChannel().antMatchers("/actuator").requiresInsecure();` the ant matcher `"/actuator"` doesn't match `" /actuator/info"`. Try changing it to `"/actuator/**"`.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I ran into the same problem.

Comment: You can use 2 ports: 1 for management, 1 for server (https). It's work fine.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same without using two different ports?

Comment: For single port we only can use http or https (one of them)

Answer (score 4):

In case anybody stumbles over this as well. I solved it using 2 Ports like @user3611168 suggested:

applycation.yml:

```
  server:
    port: 10000
    ssl:
      key-store-type: ...
      key-store: ...
      key-store-password: ...
      key-alias: ...
  management:
    server:
      port: 8080
      ssl:
        enabled: false
```

Port 10000 with SSL. Port for Prometheus 8080 without SSL